# Running the coaxial cable through the wall from an ANTENNA NOT A CABLE BOX

Tags: walls, television, tv-antenna

The coaxial cable will be connected to an outside tv antenna, then run through the wall to the TV.  Do I need a cable box for the coaxial cable or the cable box just for cable tv?
This is a single story house and I want to run the coax through the wall closest to where I have  the TV.

Comment: When you say "cable box" do you mean an enclosure in which you splice cables?  Or do you mean an electronic gadget the size of a phone book, that is warm, has LEDs, with a wireless remote that lets you pick channels, that typically comes with cable TV?

Comment: Do you have a discharge unit/grounding block/surge suppressor at the antenna already?

Answer (score 1):

You can poke a hole in the wall and push the cable through the hole , no box is required (this is how a cable company will do it), I usually use a low voltage ring like a wbf-1 this provides a way to mount a cover plate. 
Make sure to seal the entry cable and hole with a quality silicone sealer. 
Your needs for a TV cable box depends on what you have available in your area. At my last home on the side of a mountain I had great digital reception. One of my tv’s had the decoder built in and I purchased a box for ~$10.00 for another. So it depends on your area so we won’t know the answer to that one.